# Basic python client/server that reads HTML body from server.

Tags: python, html, sockets, http, client-server

I am writing a very simple Python socket program to read an HTML body from the server. If I create a HelloWorld.html file and open it with the designated host and port, I can open the file in my browser with the following server and read the message in the HTML file. However, I am having trouble reading in the same information from my client.

**Server**

```
from socket import *
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 6789
serverSocket.bind((host,port))
serverSocket.listen(5)
print("server started...") 
(connectionSocket, addr) = serverSocket.accept()
try: 
    message = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode()
    filename = message.split()[1]
    f = open(filename[1:]) # Throws IOError if file not found
    print(filename, "found")
    connectionSocket.send("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n".encode())
    connectionSocket.send("Content-Type: text/html\r\n".encode())
    connectionSocket.send(message.encode())
    outputdata = f.read() 
    for i in range(0, len(outputdata)): 
        connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i].encode())
    connectionSocket.send("\r\n".encode()) 
    connectionSocket.close()
    print(filename, "delivered")
except IOError:
    print(filename, "NOT found")
    connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND\r\n')
    connectionSocket.close()
    print("file not found message delivered")
serverSocket.close()
print("server closed...")
```

My server seems to be working. However, when my client tries to send the HTML object path to the socket and have the server read it, it does not seem to be picking up the message. I have just started socket programming in Python and I am trying to understand how the server receives the message from the socket. My initial thought was if I send the path of the HTML object (located in same directory as client and server) to the socket, the server should be able to read that information, open it, and return the information to the client.

**Client**

```
from socket import *
import sys

client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

host = sys.argv[1]
port = sys.argv[2]
obj = sys.argv[3]

port = int(port)
client.connect((host, port))

print(client.getsockname())

request = obj

client.send("hello".encode())
client.send(request.encode())

s = client.recv(1024).decode()

print(s)
```

For my client, I accept the host,port, and the path to the HTML from a commandline argument and establish a connection.

When I run the browser for my HTML file with the url *http://127.0.0.1:6789/HelloWorld.html*, the server responds well. However, when I run the server and run the client with the command *py capClient.py 127.0.0.1 6789 HelloWorld.html* on the shell, it returns the **filename = message.split()[1] IndexError: list index out of range** error. I am assuming that this problem is coming from the server not being able to split the message coming in from the connectionSocket as an acceptable HTML object path.

What are some tips on modifying the client code to receive HTML file from servers?

Answer (score 0):

This trouble is because you await `message` string is `'hello HelloWorld.html'`, but it is `'helloHelloWorld.html'` and `split()` get you list `['helloHelloWorld.html']` where index 1 not exists.

```
    f = open(filename[1:])
    # must be replaced with [1:] give you a list, not string
    f = open(filename)

    # there needs encode()
    connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND\r\n'.encode())
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is there an efficient way to split the messages into two so it does not end up being concatenated?

Comment: i don't think that this method exist, message it is just bytes string, you can add some special marks or spaces or '\n' or '\r\n' for example as marker of new string at client side.